# Decoding all the called from database using ajax data in td format in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to decode the the data i got from I called from my controller using ajax I used "JSON.parse"
but didn't work can any body help me to fix it
Controller code:

```
 public function ajax(Request $request)
      {
        $user_data=$request->session()->get('user_name');
        $reports=Complaint::Where('raised_by','=',"$user_data")->SELECT('*')->get();
       return response()->json([
    'report' => $reports,]);
      }
```

ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
      {

        $.ajax({
          url:'{{route('complain_ajax')}}',
          method:'GET',
          dataType:'JSON',
          success:function(response)
          {
            var report=JSON.parse(response.report);
            alert(report);
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

cant find a way out

Comment: dont need to parse.. its already a json.

Answer (score 0):

As ZeroOne said, no need to parse.

In your controller:

```
return $reports;
```

In your javascript you should be able to iterate your data or do whatever you need:

```
      success:function(response)
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var complaint = response[i];
        }
      }
```